# Is it cheaper to store a string or convert it to bytes32 with abi.encodePacked()?

Tags: solidity, gas, bytes, bytes32

For example, in the code below, would it be cheaper to store the `string` in a `mapping`? Or to convert it to `bytes32` and store it as `bytes32` then convert it back to a `string` whenever I call it with JavaScript?

```
mapping(string => bool) _tokenExists;

function test(string memory _str) public {
    _tokenExists[_str] = true;
}
```

Or

```
mapping(bytes32 => bool) _tokenExists;

function test(string memory _str) public {
    _tokenExists[abi.encodePacked(_str)] = true;
}
```

Which one of these would be cheaper & better to use and why?

PS: Is there a way I can find out on my own for the future which would be cheaper by doing my own gas estimates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `abi.encodePacked(_str)` will convert the `string` `_str` to its UTF-8 `bytes` representation, and not to `bytes32`. `bytes` is a [dynamically-sized byte array](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array), as is `string`. Since [Solidity 0.8.5](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.8.5) it’s possible to cast `bytes` into `bytes32`, but you need to pay attention because anything beyond 32 bytes will be chopped off.

So if your `string`’s UTF-8 `bytes` representation is 32 bytes or shorter, you can place it in a `bytes32` via `bytes32(abi.encodePacked(_str))`, whereas if your string is longer than 32 bytes, you can compress it into a `bytes32` via `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str))`.

---

From the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays):

> The value corresponding to a mapping key `k` is located at `keccak256(h(k) . p)` where `.` is concatenation and `h` is a function that is applied to the key depending on its type:
>
> - for value types, `h` pads the value to 32 bytes in the same way as when storing the value in memory.
> - for strings and byte arrays, `h` computes the `keccak256` hash of the unpadded data.

`p` above is the “slot position” for the mapping variable (your `_tokenExists`), so within a contract it is constant. For this example, suppose that `p = 0`. So we have:

| Type of key `k` | Value slot position |
| --- | --- |
| `bytes32` | `keccak256( k . 0 )` |
| `bytes` or `string` | `keccak256( keccak256(abi.encodePacked(k)) . 0 )` |

So for `mapping`s with `bytes` or `string` key-type, accessing a `mapping` value invokes an extra `keccak256`. But invoking `keccak256` is [cheap enough](https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes) to not let it influence your design decisions. Rather you should use `string` or `bytes32` depending on what is semantically more suitable for your contract.

---

A simple way to test the theory above “on your own, for the future” is by loading in [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) a test-contract, deploying it to the `JavaScript VM` `Environment`, and invoking the different functions with the same input strings, trying both short and long strings, and comparing the different functions’ `execution cost`, e.g.:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract Test {
    mapping(string => bool) _tokenExists1;
    function test1(string memory _str) external {
        _tokenExists1[_str] = true;
    }

    mapping(bytes => bool) _tokenExists2;
    function test2(string memory _str) external {
        _tokenExists2[abi.encodePacked(_str)] = true;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => bool) _tokenExists3;
    function test3(string memory _str) external {
        _tokenExists3[keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str))] = true;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => bool) _tokenExists4;
    function test4(string memory _str) external {
        _tokenExists4[bytes32(abi.encodePacked(_str))] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So you're saying that instead of using a `string` as the key for a `mapping`, I should instead do `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(string))` to store that string as a `bytes32` & save on gas if it's longer than 32 bytes? & do `bytes32(abi.encodePacked(string))` to store the `string` as a key if it's less than or equal to 32 bytes?

Comment: Not letting my other comment for some reason. I just ran the functions you gave me and it seems just using a `string` as a key is the cheapest choice. However, would the best choice be using the front end to pass in a `bytes32` value and store it as a `bytes32` and not convert it in Solidity?

Comment: When you use `string` as a mapping key, internally Solidity will still calculate `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(key))` every time you access a value (i.e. `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are effectively the same), so it’s better to let the Solidity compiler do it for you itself (`test1`) and keep your code clean. I forgot to include `test5` for comparison, where you pass a ready-hashed `bytes32` directly yourself… but even if there are any gas differences, they will be small, so if for your application it makes sense to use `string` keys, then use `string` keys and keep your Solidity/JS code simple.